# formBuilder validator pattern is not working

Tags: angular, forms, validation, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to show a message if the password is not compatible with formGroup pattern.

FormGroup init:

```
this.signupForm = fb.group({
  userName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^\S*$/),Validators.pattern(`^[a-z0-9_-]{8,15}$`)])],
  image:[''],
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, EmailValidator.isValid])],
  password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern(`^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$`)])],
  confirm: ['', Validators.required]
  }, {
  validator: PasswordValidation.MatchPassword
});
```

Html:

```
      <ion-item no-lines>
        <ion-label floating>
          <ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon>Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName="password"  formControlName="password" type="password"></ion-input>
          <ion-icon  class="alert" *ngIf="signupForm.get('password').hasError('pattern')" name="alert-outline" item-right></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
```

`signupForm.get('password').hasError('pattern')` is always false!

> signupForm.get('password').hasError('required')
>
> and signupForm.get('password').touched are working well

Any one tell me where is my problem?

Comment: Please post PasswordValidation.MatchPassword code.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't exist an icon named `alert-outline`:

[image]

So what you are probably looking for is `ios-alert-outline`, so you would want to do...

```
<ion-icon *ngIf="..." md="ios-alert-outline" ios="ios-alert-outline" ..></ion-icon>
```

which works just fine... **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bwkbnm?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**